# Cases appear on my dashboard "My Cases" but no cases appear on CiviMobile App (android)

Tags: civimobile

I can't see any Cases in the mobile app. Running Drupal core 7.69, CiviCRM 5.20.2, CiviMobileAPI 4.2.1. The account I'm using has administrative privileges.

When I login to my website a view cases I can see the following: 
[image]

But when I view cases on the mobile app I don't have any cases. 
[image]

Has anybody else seen this? Any tips on resolving? I am able to see case activities.

Thank you.

Comment: Have things improved with the more recent versions of this app eg 5.20

Answer (score 0):

Have you found a solution to this?

It appears that the only cases that populate the "Cases" page in the mobile app are those in which you are the client, rather than the case manager or any other case role...

Comment: Correct, you have to be the "client" at this point for the mobile app to work. Fortunately assigned activities from cases appear in the app so we were good to go with the app "as is".